# Spinor decomposition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, representation-theory, spinors

I just read in the book "Covariant loop quantum gravity" of Rovelli about spinors (section 1.7.1) I'm confused about the decomposition of an spinor of two indices that it is done:

$$z^{AB}= z_0 \epsilon^{AB} + z^{(AB)} $$

where $z^{(AB)}$ is the symmetric part,  $\epsilon$ is the antisymmetric matrix and $z_0 = (1/2)\epsilon_{AB}z^{AB}$.

I understand the symmetric part but I'm rather confused with the anti symmetric part that should be $(1/2)(z^{AB}-z^{BA})$. How can I obtain the expression given by Rovelli?

Comment: Hint: In a two dimensional space, the only antisymmetric tensor is $\epsilon_{AB}$. So any antisymmetric tensor must be proportional to it.

Comment: Thanks! So since the antisymmetric part must be proportional to the antisymmetric tensor, then the scalar $z_0$ can only be build from the spinor and the antysimmetric tensor itself. Yet I still have the question of how can the expression $z_0 \epsilon^{AB}$ can be obtained from $(1/2)(z^{AB}-z^{BA})$ using algebraic methods.

Comment: You answered your question. Equate $(1/2) (z^{AB} - z^{BA}) = z_{0} \epsilon^{AB}$ and solve for $z_{0}$. This equation is the statement that an antisymmetric tensor is proportional to $\epsilon$. The c-number $z_{0}$ is the proportionality constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
z_0 \epsilon^{AB} &=& \frac 1 2 \epsilon _{CD}\,z^{CD} \times \epsilon^{AB}\;,\\
&=& \frac 1 2 \delta^{AB}_{CD} \,z^{CD} \;,\\
&=& \frac 1 2 \big(   z^{AB}-z^{BA}  \big)\;,
\end{eqnarray}
where 
$$
\epsilon _{CD}\,\epsilon^{AB}= \delta^{AB}_{CD} \equiv \det  \begin{bmatrix}   \delta^A_C & \delta^A_D \\ \delta^B_C & \delta^B_D\end{bmatrix}\;,
$$